# Calculate the amount of objects inside array field in a MonogDb document

Tags: mongodb

How can group all the documents with the same id in a certain field, and calculate the length of the array inside one of them field.

Like in my case below , the result should be:

```
{ 
    movieId: ("5b79b8387d467d5ab860544f")
    takenSeats : 46 
}

{ 
   movieId : ("5b79b9277d467d5ab8605454")
   takenSeats : 11

}

{
   movieId : ("5b79b8927d467d5ab8605451")
   takenSeats: 17
}
```

[image: MongoDb]

This is how I started the aggregation:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
        { $match:{ "created":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*15)}}}, 
        { $lookup: { from: "shows", localField: "showId", foreignField: "_id", as: "acociatedShow" }},
        { $unwind: "$acociatedShow" }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$acociatedShow" } },
        { $group: {_id: '$_id' ,movieId: { $first: '$movie' },takenSeats: { $first: '$takenSeats' }}}, 
 ])
```

[Edit]

Result using:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
        { $match:{ "created":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*15)}}}, 
        { $lookup: { from: "shows", localField: "showId", foreignField: "_id", as: "acociatedShow" }},
        { $unwind: "$acociatedShow" }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$acociatedShow" } },
          { $group: {_id: '$movie',takenSeats: { $sum: {$size:'$takenSeats' }}}}
 ])
```

[image]

I get the wanted result with this query, but the question is can I make it shorter without the `$push` operator

```
db.orders.aggregate([
        { $match:{ "created":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*15)}}}, 
        { $lookup: { from: "shows", localField: "showId", foreignField: "_id", as: "acociatedShow" }},
        { $unwind: "$acociatedShow" }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$acociatedShow" } },
        { $group: {_id: '$_id' ,movieId: { $first: '$movie' },takenSeats: { $first: '$takenSeats' }}}, 
        { $unwind: "$takenSeats" },       
        { $group:{ _id: "$movieId","takenSeats":{"$push": "$takenSeats"}}},
 ])
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `$group` by movie and `$size` to count the elements in `takenSeats` array for each movie with `$sum` to count for each key. Something like `{ $group: {_id: '$movie' },takenSeats: { $sum: {$size:'$takenSeats' }}}` instead of your `$group`.

Comment: @Veeram  I tried that already but as i understand the `$size` operator only works in the `$project` stage, any way i did it and it throws me this error `"errmsg" : "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field`

Comment: Sorry try `{ $group: {_id: '$movie',takenSeats: { $sum: {$size:'$takenSeats' }}}}`. I had a syntax error. `$size` operator works in both `$project` and `$group`.

Comment: @Veeram I did it and edited the question with the result, the valus are incorrect.

Comment: @Veeram  yesterday after you helped me i recived the my wanted result, but it looks like i can get it shorter (i edited the question again)